# Spacer between elements in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, qt, user-interface

What shall i use to make a spacer between elements in visual studio like that in QT
http://www.tuxradar.com/files/qt_menq_spacers.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use the `Margin` and `Padding` properties of any control to that end.

**Edit:** In response to your comment, I get the impression that your main goal is not to add a certain amount of space between controls (which would be what the `Margin` and `Padding` properties are for), but that you want to *align* controls along certain lines or edges. In Winforms, this is usually done via a combination of panels and the proper use of a control's `Anchor` and `Dock` properties.

Comment: i am sorry but see this photo i think u will get what i mean http://img26.yfrog.com/img26/327/76992562.png the ui elements dont resize well

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Anchor` property to position controls relative to the dialogs edges.

And you can use a couple of panels to separate controls into different areas.
But I don´t think there is some thing like the spacers you mentioned in the question.